# Page Preloading Effect - Load and execute once

Tags: cookies, loading, session-cookies, preloader

I am using the [Page Preloading Effect](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/08/05/page-preloading-effect/) so that my home page can load. I need to workout how to ensure it only executes once on landing on the site. At the moment every time the home page is visited it executes the preloading effect. Presumably I can use a cookie but I am a little unsure where to start!
Thanks :)

Comment: ,Are you looking for a Preloader, a animation untill page loads completely?

Comment: Yes because I have a large image that needs to appear when the user comes to the site. I have optimised and reduced the size of the image as much as I can but its still quite large so I thought a reloading animation while this loads to enhance usability.

Comment: try my solution and feel free to ask if you stuck somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use jQuery to accomplish this task. In you HTML page add following code inside body tag.

```
        <div class="loader">
         <h5 class="loaderH">Preparing. ...</h5>
       </div>
```

Now below is CSS for above HTML Tags

```
        .loader {
            position: fixed;
            left: 0px;
            top: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: 9999;
            background: url('../../images/loaders/preloader.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(249,249,249);
        }

        .loaderH{
            position: fixed;
            left: 45vw;
            top: 55vh;
        }
```

And Finally user jquery to load before page is ready.

```
        $(window).load(function() {
            $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
            console.log('loaded');
        })
```

**Don't forget to change background URL src**
            background: url('../../images/loaders/preloader.gif') 50% 50% no-    repeat rgb(249,249,249);

For preloader you can use following.

http://www.ajaxload.info/images/exemples/26.gif
http://www.mandalayonlinestore.com/assets/img/loader.gif

**Or just google preloader gif**